# wp_update_post recieving an array from within or outside of a set of IF / ELSE statements

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update certain post type's posts (testimonial, client, project), based on an *Advanced Custom Field (ACF)* field.

**Version 1** generates the post in the correct post type, but the code repeats *wp_update_post* in every IF / ELSE statement. **Version 2**'s code only has *wp_update_post* once, outside of the IF / ELSE; but in addition to posting in the correct post type, it also generates a blank entry in the *'post'* post type.

In either case, looking at the post_id's, for each post that is made, the post_id appears to increase by a factor of 3.

My question is; is this behaviour expected? So far as the difference in *wp_update_post* is concerned. Furthermore, is the post_id jump by a factor of 3 normal?

**VERSION 1: wp_update_post within every IF / ELSE**

```
// ACF Auto Titles
function my_post_title_updater( $post_id ) {

  if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'testimonial' ) {

    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_556ea5ac8c15b]; // Name
    $testimonial_field = $_POST['acf'][field_556ea5c68c15c]; // Testimonial

    $my_post = array(
      'ID' => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $name_field . ' - \'' . $testimonial_field . '\'',
      'post_name' => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );

   } elseif ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'client' ) {

    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_55749b0918a33]; // Name

    $my_post = array(
      'ID' => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $name_field,
      'post_name' => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );

  } elseif ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'project' ) {

    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_557546848cfd9]; // Name

    $my_post = array(
      'ID' => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $name_field,
      'post_name' => $post_id
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );

   }

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_post_title_updater', 1);
```

**VERSION 2: wp_update_post after the IF / ELSE**

```
// ACF Auto Titles
function my_post_title_updater( $post_id ) {

  if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'testimonial' ) {

    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_556ea5ac8c15b]; // Name
    $testimonial_field = $_POST['acf'][field_556ea5c68c15c]; // Testimonial

    $my_post = array(
      'ID' => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $name_field . ' - \'' . $testimonial_field . '\'',
      'post_name' => $post_id
    );

   } elseif ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'client' ) {

    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_55749b0918a33]; // Name

    $my_post = array(
      'ID' => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $name_field,
      'post_name' => $post_id
    );

  } elseif ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'project' ) {

    $name_field = $_POST['acf'][field_557546848cfd9]; // Name

    $my_post = array(
      'ID' => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $name_field,
      'post_name' => $post_id
    );

   }

wp_update_post( $my_post );

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_post_title_updater', 1);
```

**How Posts Appear in phpMyAdmin**
[image: How Posts Appear in phpMyAdmin]

Answer (score 0):

About **Version 2**, you have to make sure that a valid post type was processed at all. If `get_post_type()` didn't match any of your `IF` statements, `$my_post` would be undefined, and an empty update will occur. You should therefore change your update statement to:

```
if (isset( $my_post ))
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: By updating 3 times, do you mean... 1) Initial Save. 2) wp_update_post. 3) 'Publish' Save? One increment in the post_id for each revision?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I removed that part of my answer. I'm not sure why it's increasing by 3. Perhaps a MySQL [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) value of 3? Try enabling your DB's general log to see what's going on.

Comment: I've added a screenshot what it looks like in the wp_posts table when I update a single post to the main question.